# Merge multiple delimited file to Hive using ODI

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hive

Basically I have 3 input file and I need to merge the 3 input file to Hive using ODI.

file 1:
AcctNo,Name,Address

file 2 :
AcctNo,Block_Code,Block_Date

file 3 :
AcctNo,Balance1,Balance2

Hive :
AcctNo,Name,Address,Block_Code,Block_Date,Balance1,Balance2

I'm pretty new to Hadoop and I been throw into this project without a proper training with Oracle Data Integration, I read that hive natively does not support update but can be enable ACID transaction.

Since my organisation using ODI as main data integration tools, I need it to be done in ODI, can anyone enlighten me can this to be done in 1 time ETL?

I was thinking to do a ETL from file to Hive first without merge, then only do a merge within HIVE, bit it seem time consuming. I wonder is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

In my option you could load the files into [HDFS](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html) either using ODI or FTPS. Once the data is in HDFS you have the flexibility to [create external tables](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.5/using-hiveql/content/hive_create_an_external_table.html) which would simply create a logical table and then you could join/merge them into a separate table.

- Loading the files into HDFS using hadoop CLI:

`hadoop fs -copyFromLocal file1.csv /user/cloudera/data/file1`

`/user/cloudera/data` is the HDFS path you need to provide as per your project.

- Creating External Table in hive:

  ```
  create external table file1_table(
   AcctNo string,
   Name string,
   Address string
  ) row format delimited
  fields terminated by ','  -- assuming your file is comma separated
  stored as textfile 
  location '/user/cloudera/data/file1' -- the hdfs location
  tblproperties("skip.header.line.count"="1"); -- assuming file is having a header section.
  ```
- Once you have the external tables ready, you could create a table which you join all of the tables (file1_table, file2_table, file3_table) together into a single view.